# What can be the next move without guessing in this almost solved Sudoku puzzle?

Tags: sudoku, solvability

I am currently stuck at this puzzle where I can't think of the next move without *guessing* it. I was surprised to be in this situation after solving ~70-80% of the puzzle. I thought for all possible logical ways but I couldn't figure out the next move without guessing something.

```
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│ 3 │ 8 │ 4 │ 6 │ 2 │ 1 │ 9 │ 7 │ 5 │
│ 9 │ 5 │ 2 │   │   │   │ 4 │ 6 │ 1 │
│ 1 │ 6 │ 7 │ 5 │ 9 │ 4 │ 3 │ 2 │ 8 │
│───┼───┼───│───┼───┼───│───┼───┼───│
│ 5 │ 2 │ 3 │ 4 │ 7 │ 8 │ 6 │ 1 │ 9 │
│ 6 │ 4 │ 9 │   │ 1 │   │ 8 │ 5 │ 7 │
│ 8 │ 7 │ 1 │ 9 │ 6 │ 5 │ 2 │   │   │
│───┼───┼───│───┼───┼───│───┼───┼───│
│   │ 9 │ 6 │   │ 5 │   │ 1 │   │   │
│   │ 1 │ 8 │   │   │ 6 │ 5 │ 9 │   │
│ 2 │ 3 │ 5 │ 1 │   │ 9 │ 7 │   │ 6 │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

Can someone explain the next logical move I should do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this seems to be an invalid Sudoku. It has multiple solutions, and therefore there is no logical next move.

> Solution 1
>
> `+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
> | 3 | 8 | 4 | 6 | 2 | 1 | 9 | 7 | 5 |
> | 9 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 8 | 7 | 4 | 6 | 1 |
> | 1 | 6 | 7 | 5 | 9 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 8 |
> │───┼───┼───│───┼───┼───│───┼───┼───│
> | 5 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 7 | 8 | 6 | 1 | 9 |
> | 6 | 4 | 9 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 8 | 5 | 7 |
> | 8 | 7 | 1 | 9 | 6 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
> │───┼───┼───│───┼───┼───│───┼───┼───│
> | 7 | 9 | 6 | 8 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 3 |
> | 4 | 1 | 8 | 7 | 3 | 6 | 5 | 9 | 2 |
> | 2 | 3 | 5 | 1 | 4 | 9 | 7 | 8 | 6 |
> +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+`
>
>
> Solution 2
>
> `+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
> | 3 | 8 | 4 | 6 | 2 | 1 | 9 | 7 | 5 |
> | 9 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 8 | 7 | 4 | 6 | 1 |
> | 1 | 6 | 7 | 5 | 9 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 8 |
> │───┼───┼───│───┼───┼───│───┼───┼───│
> | 5 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 7 | 8 | 6 | 1 | 9 |
> | 6 | 4 | 9 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 8 | 5 | 7 |
> | 8 | 7 | 1 | 9 | 6 | 5 | 2 | 4 | 3 |
> │───┼───┼───│───┼───┼───│───┼───┼───│
> | 7 | 9 | 6 | 8 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 4 |
> | 4 | 1 | 8 | 7 | 3 | 6 | 5 | 9 | 2 |
> | 2 | 3 | 5 | 1 | 4 | 9 | 7 | 8 | 6 |
> +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+`
>
>
> Solution 3
>
> `+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
> | 3 | 8 | 4 | 6 | 2 | 1 | 9 | 7 | 5 |
> | 9 | 5 | 2 | 7 | 8 | 3 | 4 | 6 | 1 |
> | 1 | 6 | 7 | 5 | 9 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 8 |
> │───┼───┼───│───┼───┼───│───┼───┼───│
> | 5 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 7 | 8 | 6 | 1 | 9 |
> | 6 | 4 | 9 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 8 | 5 | 7 |
> | 8 | 7 | 1 | 9 | 6 | 5 | 2 | 4 | 3 |
> │───┼───┼───│───┼───┼───│───┼───┼───│
> | 4 | 9 | 6 | 8 | 5 | 7 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
> | 7 | 1 | 8 | 2 | 3 | 6 | 5 | 9 | 4 |
> | 2 | 3 | 5 | 1 | 4 | 9 | 7 | 8 | 6 |
> +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+`
>
>
> Solution 4
>
> `+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
> | 3 | 8 | 4 | 6 | 2 | 1 | 9 | 7 | 5 |
> | 9 | 5 | 2 | 8 | 3 | 7 | 4 | 6 | 1 |
> | 1 | 6 | 7 | 5 | 9 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 8 |
> │───┼───┼───│───┼───┼───│───┼───┼───│
> | 5 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 7 | 8 | 6 | 1 | 9 |
> | 6 | 4 | 9 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 8 | 5 | 7 |
> | 8 | 7 | 1 | 9 | 6 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
> │───┼───┼───│───┼───┼───│───┼───┼───│
> | 4 | 9 | 6 | 7 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 8 | 3 |
> | 7 | 1 | 8 | 3 | 4 | 6 | 5 | 9 | 2 |
> | 2 | 3 | 5 | 1 | 8 | 9 | 7 | 4 | 6 |
> +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+`
>
>
> Solution 5
>
> `+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
> | 3 | 8 | 4 | 6 | 2 | 1 | 9 | 7 | 5 |
> | 9 | 5 | 2 | 8 | 3 | 7 | 4 | 6 | 1 |
> | 1 | 6 | 7 | 5 | 9 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 8 |
> │───┼───┼───│───┼───┼───│───┼───┼───│
> | 5 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 7 | 8 | 6 | 1 | 9 |
> | 6 | 4 | 9 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 8 | 5 | 7 |
> | 8 | 7 | 1 | 9 | 6 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
> │───┼───┼───│───┼───┼───│───┼───┼───│
> | 4 | 9 | 6 | 7 | 5 | 3 | 1 | 8 | 2 |
> | 7 | 1 | 8 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 5 | 9 | 3 |
> | 2 | 3 | 5 | 1 | 8 | 9 | 7 | 4 | 6 |
> +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+`